# Changing matlab background colors

Tags: matlab

This code

```
  1 function makegraph(A,B)
  2 results=load(A);
  3 time = results(:,3) - 1238370000;
  4 firstTimeIndex = find(time >= (max(time) - 86400*7), 1);
  5 results = results(max(1,firstTimeIndex-1):end, :);%Results now only containe    s data from the last week 
  6 temp = results(:,3)-1238370000;
  7 h=plot(temp,smooth(results(:,1)),':b','linewidth',2)
  8 ylim([0 80])
  9 xlim([max(temp)-(86400*7),max(temp)-1])
 10 set(gca,'color','black')
 11 set(gcf,'color','black') %get's rid of he axis alltogether
 12 hold on
 13 plot(temp, smooth(results(:,4)), 'r', 'linewidth', 2);
 14 plot(temp, smooth(results(:,5)), 'g', 'linewidth', 2);
 15 plot(temp, smooth(results(:,6)), 'm', 'linewidth', 2);
 16 xlim([max(temp)-(86400*7),max(temp)-1])
 17 set(gca,'XTick',[1:86400:(max(temp))+1])
 18 set(gca,'XTickLabel',['Mon';'Tue';'Wed';'Thu';'Fri';'Sat';'Sun'])
 19 print('-djpeg',B)
 20 hold off
```

Saves this graph in the filename 'B'...[image]

It works fine, but I'd like to put it in a different context, for which I need it to have a black background...

I have tried setting

```
set(gca,'color',[1 1 0])
set(gcf,'color',[1 1 0])
```

as described by [Setting the background color of a plot in MATLAB using the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291651/setting-the-background-color-of-a-plot-in-matlab-using-the-command-line)

and I've tried

```
whitebg(1,'k')
```

...and I'm getting nowhere -particualarly because sometimes when I try and play around with some of

set(gca,'color','black')
    set(gcf,'color','black') settings, some of my plots disappear.

I'm deeply confused.. could someone tell me why the accepted answer at [Setting the background color of a plot in MATLAB using the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291651/setting-the-background-color-of-a-plot-in-matlab-using-the-command-line) isn't working here...?

Comment: What is B?  Do you have this problem in the figure displayed in matlab or only in the printed file?

Comment: you should try to use the handle of the figure\axes directly, instead of using gca\gcf

Comment: @Molly B is the filename - have edited - and it turned out I was looking at the printed file... which helped me solve it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that the commands were working within MATLAB, they just weren't working on the printed file because, according to http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/print.html....

> By default, MATLAB changes the figure background color of printed
>   output to white, but does not change the color of uicontrols. If you
>   have set the background color, for example, to match the gray of the
>   GUI devices, you must set InvertHardcopy to off to preserve the color
>   scheme. To set InvertHardcopy on the current figure, use the command:
>   set(gcf,'InvertHardcopy','off')

So once I set set(gcf,'InvertHardcopy','off'), everything was peachy... thanks in particular to Molly, who put me on the right track...